# getParent function not working in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

i have this function :

```
jQuery.fn.getParent = function(num) {
var last = this[0];
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    last = last.parentNode;
}
return jQuery(last);
};
```

and this html :

```
<div class="statuscontainer">
<div class="title">
Title of div here
</div>
blah blah blah blah <br>
<a onclick="$(this).getParent(4).fadeTo("slow",.3);">fade only this div</a>
</div>


<div class="statuscontainer">
<div class="title">
Title of div here
</div>
blah blah blah blah <br>
<a onclick="$(this).getParent(4).fadeTo("slow",.3);">fade only this div</a>
</div>
```

what i want, that each link should fade it's main  statuscontainer div and not all other divs, that's done using jQuery GetParent.

that's works great in firefox/chrome/safari, but in IE 7/8 , only the blah blah blah and the link are faded and not the entire "statuscontainer".

What do you suggest ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what's wrong in the code, it seems straightforward enough.

Maybe using one of these JQuery functions helps?

- [**parents**](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents)
- [**closest**](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest)

I'm assuming that being core functions of JQuery, any cross-browser issues are likely to have been resolved there.

Comment: thanks for answer, the problem which i just realized that some other divs inside storycontainer are not fading! i don't know why only in IE

Comment: Maybe it's because they don't have layout (try the `zoom: 1` CSS property) or something along that line? IE often has issues fading elements.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, i found the solution , some divs which are not faded, are positioned in "relative", once i deleted the positioning , it worked :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `jQuery('theElementSelector').parents(':eq(3)')`? Note I didn't look what index you were actually after, but it should be 3 or 4 depending.

Comment: thanks for answer, the problem which i just realized that some other divs inside storycontainer are not fading! i don't know why only in IE

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `$(this).closest('.statuscontainer').fadeTo()` instead. That way no matter where the `<a>` is in the DOM - it will find the closest `.statuscontainer` in the parents. [`.closest()` docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest)

Comment: thanks for answer, the problem which i just realized that some other divs inside storycontainer are not fading! i don't know why only in IE